# How to make request like this Apache1 -> Squid -> Apache2

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy, squid

i have a site i want to embedded to my page. but it get blocked. i can access my web server. i want to make a request like we currently use squid.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="https://openload.co/embed/mePxK8Kdb54/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="640" height="360" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

so the case will like this

```
Client -> Apache1 -> Squid -> Apache2
Client <- Apache1 <- Squid <- Apache2
```

What i need to setup for Apache1? Forward or Reverse? and how to send the request to squid and get the result?

The site that get blocked is openload.co.